# Allow other developers to access some of my AWS Lambda code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

Is there any way to grant another developer limited access to view and modify the code for one of my AWS Lambda functions? Obviously I don't want to share my Amazon login, but can AWS be configured to allow team development?

Comment: That what VCS is for (like Git).

Comment: What Sergey suggested. Alternatively you can deploy lambdas from s3 bucket, for which you give access to people that want to get the code, but that is weird and unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to modify code on AWS Lambda console is for someone to try it out quickly, or for some really small functionality. As your function grows in complexity, it will become increasingly difficult to manage your code directly through the console.

I would recommend staying away from this practice, keep your code in a code repository, to which you can give access to others.

This will also enable you to use a CI tool to seamlessly build and deploy new changes to the lambda function without going to the console.